# Find if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{1+\frac1{2}+\frac1{3}+\dots+\frac1{n}}$, $a > 0$ converges or not.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Find if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{1+\frac1{2}+\frac1{3}+\dots+\frac1{n}}$, $a >0$ converges or not.

I used d'Alembert's criterion and I found $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}}=1$

Moving to Raabe–Duhamel's test, I found $$\lim_{n\to \infty} n(\frac{x_n}{x_{n+1}} -1) =  \lim_{n\to \infty} n(\frac{1}{\sqrt[n+1]{a}} - 1) $$

What can I do from there? Or is there a better way to find if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a^{1+\frac1{2}+\frac1{3}+\dots+\frac1{n}}$, $a >0$ converges or not?

Comment: Do you know about Harmonic Series?

Comment: Yes, I know that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac1{n}$ is divergent

Comment: If $ a\ge 1$ the series diverges.

Comment: And if a <1? Then it is equal with $\frac{1}{1-x_n}$?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First owing to the concavity of the logarithm function, we have

$$\int_1^n \frac1x\,dx\le \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k \le 1+\int_1^n \frac1x\,dx$$

Therefore, for $1>a>0$ we have

$$a^{\log(n)+1}\le a^{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k}\le a^{\log(n)}$$

while for $a\ge 1$ we have

$$a^{\log(n)}\le a^{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1k}\le a^{\log(n)+1}$$

Thus, using $a^{\log(n)}=n^{\log(a)}$ we find from by "the p-test" that the series converges whenever $0<a<1/e$ and diverges for $a\ge 1/e$.

Comment: Thank you! Why does the series diverge when $a\ge1/e$? For the p-test we want $-\log{a}$ to be $> 1$ for the series to be convergent, right?

Comment: Is this right? $n^{\log(a)}= \frac{1}{n^{-\log(a)}}$.  For p-test: $-\log(a) >1$ => $\log{\frac1{a}}$ > $\log e$ => $\frac1{a}>e$ => $\frac1{e}>a.$ So then for $ \frac1{e}>a$ it converges?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: You got your last sentence wrong. The series converges for $a < e^{-1}$ and diverges for $a \geqslant e^{-1}$.

Comment: @danielfischer Indeed.  I had it correct but am working from my "not-so-smart-phone" and when making changes, was careless and didn't change the language.

Answer (score 3):

**hint**

You can use the fact that the sequence
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac 1k-\ln(n)$$

converges to Euler's constant $\gamma$.